# Junit 3, get data from tests

Tags: junit, junit3

I want to show some data in my GUI from my tests. I'm using JUnit 3 because other applications that I use are using that one. So if I use JUnit 4 it will collapse. I know that the possibilities in JUnit 4 are much bigger en better. But I can't use that, So I have some questions:

I know you can get some data from the JUnit 3 tests, but some data I can't find:
- How can I get the runtime of each/all tests?
- How can I get the testname of the each test that failes?
- How can I get the testnames of each test that was correct?

I looked in this API, but I can find it: http://www.junit.org/junit/javadoc/3.8.1/

I use JUnit 3.8.2, but couldn't find that API.

Comment: how do you run/execute junit?

Comment: I start the Unit tests from my own Java code. Because I need to run it from Velocity code in a CMS system. (junit.textui.TestRunner runner = new junit.textui.TestRunner(); TestResult testresult = junit.textui.TestRunner.run(runner.getTest(MyTestClass.class.getName()));)

Answer (score 1):

I used the ant.jar library To create a report from the Junit tests. First I set the Task and specify the properties how I want the test. And then I create the formatter witch i set to XML, So I get the XML output of the JUnit test.

Then I put the Test (in this case AllTests.class) to the Task and Execute it. And Voila I can find the report in the directory that I set in test.setTodir(.....)

```
Project project = new Project();
    JUnitTask task;
    try {
        task = new JUnitTask();
        project.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir","C:\\Reports\\XMLS"); //set temporary directory
        task.setProject(project);
        JUnitTask.SummaryAttribute sa = new JUnitTask.SummaryAttribute();
        sa.setValue("withOutAndErr");
        task.setFork(false);
        task.setPrintsummary(sa);
        Logger.info(getClass(), task.toString());
        FormatterElement formater = new FormatterElement();         
        FormatterElement.TypeAttribute type = new FormatterElement.TypeAttribute();
        type.setValue("xml");
        formater.setType(type);
        task.addFormatter(formater);
        JUnitTest test = new JUnitTest(AllTests.class.getName()); 
        test.setTodir(new File("C:\\Reports\\XMLS"));
        task.addTest(test);         
        task.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: perhaps you should clarify this solution a bit. I can see that you use the ant task, which may not be obvious for everybody :D